# Is there a way to vim diff only certain blocks in two files?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I use vimdiff as my preferred diff tool. I wonder if there is a way to vimdiff only certain blocks between two files (preferably without a plugin).

e.g. Comparing file1.py getValues() fn between line 14 - 26 to getValues() fn in file2.py between line 30 - 60

Comment: This looked promising to me https://github.com/rickhowe/spotdiff.vim but I won't mind a workflow without a plugin

Comment: Have you looked at ctags/etags?  You would need to generate tags file first but then vimdiff -t <function> should diff at that function.

Comment: This is my preferred plugin for this task: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim. To do it without a plugin would likely involve some copy-pasting, opening new buffers, etc., which is overhead that is resolved precisely by plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Plugin solutions

As already mentioned, there are several plugins:

- [BlockDiff.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2048) is an old, minimalistic plugin to view a diff between text blocks in a separate tab page.
- [linediff.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3745) is a modern, way more powerful variant that can also sync back changes and even handles merge conflicts, shows the scope with signs, etc.
- [spotdiff.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5509) has a different approach: instead of temporarily copying the areas to separate buffers (in a new tab page), it instead does the diff in the original windows and just fades out the unrelated parts.
- My own [AdvancedDiffOptions plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4996) has a `:DiffIRange` command that excludes certain lines from the diff, via a custom [`'diffexpr'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27diffexpr%27) that filters the files via shell commands. The plugin can also filter by line and pattern.

#### homemade

On Unix, you can combine shell (e.g. Bash) features with common tools (`sed`) to just feed the extracted text contents to vim:

```
vimdiff <(sed -n '14,26p' file1.py) <(sed -n '30,60p' file2.py)
```

This uses *process substitution* (`<(command)`) to run `command`, and provide its output as a temporary file descriptor, which Vim can read just like any other file. `sed` with default output suppression (`-n`) is used to selectively choose lines (via the `{range}p`rint command); you could also use `head`, `tail`, or even `grep`, depending on the situation.

This works similar to my plugin; the downside here is that *only* the selected ranges are accessible inside Vim.

Comment: Ingo Karkat
Works like a charm. In fact , I was able to compare parts inside the same file. 


But can this workflow be used while inside the vim. Something like 
file1.py is already opened in vim and I want to compare one function in it to other function file2.py. 


Something similar to `vert diffsplit file2.py` which compares the whole file

Comment: @ankitj Inside Vim, you'd have to remove all those lines you're not interested in (`:{range}delete _`), and then ensure that you don't accidentally `:write` those incomplete buffers. Plugins (at least the mentioned BlockDiff.vim) clone the selected buffer contents into scratch buffers; as that addresses the no-persistence and also enables diffing of two parts of the same buffer. So inside Vim, use of a plugin really is recommended for a good user experience.